# Create new column in string partial match-based dataframe without repeats

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with 2 columns `GL` and `GLDESC` and want to add a 3rd column called `KIND` based on some data that is inside of column `GLDESC`.

DF:

```
      GL                             GLDESC
1 515100                        Payroll-ISL
2 515900                        Payroll-ICA
3 532300                           Bulk Gas
4 551000                          Supply AB
5 551000                        Supply XPTO
6 551100                          Supply AB
7 551300                             Intern
```

For each row of the data table:

- If `GLDESC` contains the word `Payroll` anywhere in the string then I want `KIND` to be `Payroll`.
- If GLDESC contains the word `Supply` anywhere in the string then I want `KIND` to be `Supply`.
- In all other cases I want `KIND` to be `Other`.

Then, I found this:

```r
DF$KIND <- ifelse(grepl("supply", DF$GLDESC, ignore.case = T), "Supply", 
         ifelse(grepl("payroll", DF$GLDESC, ignore.case = T), "Payroll", "Other"))
```

But with that, I have everything that matches `Supply`, for example, classified. However, as in DF lines 4 and 5, the same `GL` has two `Supply`, which for me is unnecessary. In fact, I need only one type of `GLDESC` to be matched if for the same `GL` the string is repeated.

Edit: I can not delet any row. I want to have this as output:

```
GL  GLDESC   KIND

A   Supply1  Supply
A   Supply2  N/A
A   Supply3  N/A
A   Supply4  N/A
A   Supply5  N/A
A   Supply6  N/A
A   Payroll1 Payroll
B   Supply2  Supply
B   Payroll  Payroll
```

Comment: Can you show the  expected output

Comment: What do you mean by you only need one? What should happen to the other one? The row is removed from the data frame?

Comment: @Akrun just did it!

Comment: @IceCreamToucan I put a sample of output. I think I can show better what I want.

Comment: @akrun AMAZING! Thanks a lot! For real, you saved me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we need the repeating element to be `NA`, use `duplicated` on 'GLDESC' to get a  logical vector and assign those elements in 'KIND'  created with `ifelse` to `NA`

```
DF$KIND[duplicated(DF$GLDESC)] <- NA_character_
```

---

If we need to change the values by a grouping variable

```
library(dplyr)
DF  %>%
    group_by(GL) %>%
    mutate(KIND = replace(KIND, duplicated(KIND) & KIND == "Supply", NA_character_))

# A tibble: 9 x 3
# Groups:   GL [2]
#  GL    GLDESC   KIND   
#  <chr> <chr>    <chr>  
#1 A     Supply1  Supply 
#2 A     Supply2  <NA>   
#3 A     Supply3  <NA>   
#4 A     Supply4  <NA>   
#5 A     Supply5  <NA>   
#6 A     Supply6  <NA>   
#7 A     Payroll1 Payroll
#8 B     Supply2  Supply 
#9 B     Payroll  Payroll
```

---

Or with the full changes

```
 DF1 %>%
    mutate(KIND = str_remove(GLDESC, "\\d+"), 
    KIND = replace(KIND, !KIND %in% c("Supply", "Payroll"), "Othere")) %>% 
    group_by(GL) %>% 
    mutate(KIND = replace(KIND, duplicated(KIND) & KIND == "Supply", NA_character_))
```

#### data

```
DF1 <- structure(list(GL = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", 
"B"), GLDESC = c("Supply1", "Supply2", "Supply3", "Supply4", 
"Supply5", "Supply6", "Payroll1", "Supply2", "Payroll")), row.names = c(NA, 
-9L), class = "data.frame")
```